# how/where to add rDNS for an IP address

Tags: linux, dns

how/where to add a rDNS entry for an IP address in centos box. i am going to use my secondary IP address in postfix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's just for your local machine (eg. 10.0.0.1 etc), it goes into `/etc/hosts`.

If it is for a public IP, you need to contact your provider (the owner of the netblock) as they have to configure this in their DNS. Colocation providers may have web interfaces for this, but consumer-access providers typically won't let you do it.

Comment: my secondary IP address is publicly accessible and i want that if someone do a reverse lookup on this IP, they should get a proper DNS. its just a precaution so that emails that will be send through postfix, doesn't end up as spam.